# How to use MDC with playframework for java

Tags: java, logging, playframework, slf4j

1. MDC is not always working in playframework, as functions are executed in a managed thread pool.
2. In such cases, it is recommended that MDC.getCopyOfContextMap() is invoked on the original (master) thread before submitting a task to the executor.
3. But the thread pool is managed by playframework, I can't invokeMDC.getCopyOfContextMap() on the original thread.
4. Are there some solutions for java? or can I add an aspect for MDC as I can get data I need manually from context, and how to do? Thanks

Comment: In our project, we use context to pass the traceId. And I found two solutions to resolve the issue.
1. Customize HttpContextExecution
2. Customize a logger
-----------------------------------------
1. write a class to implements scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor and imitate methods of play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.
2. Just wrap the logger and put the data which got from context into MDC

Answer (score 4):

There's an [open bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7458) against Playframework for this. That bug report refers to Scala only but the same issue affects Java too since it is caused by MDC being thread-local but in Play a single request could consist be decomposed into several sub calls, each of which may be run on a different thread and the MDC is not being propagated to all of these threads.

There are some solutions proposed here:

- http://yanns.github.io/blog/2014/05/04/slf4j-mapped-diagnostic-context-mdc-with-play-framework/

Alternatively, you'll either need to wait until [the bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7458) is fixed or accept that MDC won't behave the way your expect it to.